# How to prove $(1 − \epsilon )x < \psi(x) (1 + \epsilon )x ?$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

The second Chebyshev function is defined as $$\psi(x):= \sum_{p^k\leq x} \log p.$$  Now  let $\psi(x) : R \to R$. Then $\psi(x) \sim x$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, it is said/can be proved ([see lemma 8 on page 9](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/pnt2.pdf)) - 
$$(1 − \epsilon )x < \psi(x)< (1 + \epsilon )x$$
for all sufficiently large $x$.

Is $\epsilon >1$?
How can I prove $$(1 − \epsilon )x < \psi(x) (1 + \epsilon )x     ?$$

It would be helpful if you provide a detailed proof or source of a detailed proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the definition of $\sim$. Note that $\psi(x)\sim x$ means $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$. Which means for sufficiently large $x$ you have $$\left|\frac{\psi(x)}{x}-1\right|<\epsilon \implies 1-\epsilon <\frac{\psi(x)}{x}<1+\epsilon$$